# What does Pierre Boulez mean by "sul ponticello"?

Tags: piano, strings, effects

While I was listening to [Boulez's comment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vrpTqm3lSsQ&t=27m25s) (in French...) on Pierre-Laurent Aimard's interpretation of the third Piano Sonata, I was wondering what is the "effect" Pierre Boulez is describing/imitating?

Boulez said,

> Yes — [twang onomatopeia] — quite like a *sul ponticello* effect on string instrument.

Apparently, this is related to some effect for strings, but I haven't understood the name.
This could be helpful to understand Pierre Boulez's intentions for this piece.

Thank you!

Comment: So the statement that you are asking for help with is in French? Can you translate it and put a quote of the translation in your question?

Comment: Yes, please ask a specific question with enough information that we can all try to address it.  Can you translate the whole sentence?  Without any context there is no way to answer.  It could refer to a psychological effect, or a physics effect, ... too broad.

Comment: Boulez said, 'Yes — [twang onomatopeia] — quite like a *[sul ponticello](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sul_ponticello)* effect on string instruments'.

Comment: @mcadorel : thank you very much! I was not able to understand the "sul ponticello"!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[*Sul ponticello*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_musical_terminology#sul_ponticello) is Italian and it means "on the bridge". It is a direction given to members of the strings section to apply their bows (or possibly their plucking when playing *pizzicato*) near the bridge of the instrument. Playing closer to the bridge emphasizes upper harmonics and makes the instrument sound brighter.

The opposite is [*sul tasto*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_musical_terminology#tasto). I'm not sure what the exact translation is, but it means to play closer to the fingerboard, which gives a darker, rounder, more mellow sound.

Comment: Thank you very much! And sorry for having asked some unclear question ; I was not able to understand exactly what Boulez was referring to.

Comment: @Watson That's ok! We got it sorted out.

Comment: I believe that "tasto" is Italian for "fret", but I would want check with an Italian speaker to be sure.

Comment: Tasto is also often just called a dolce sound.